# Android: Best practice for logging sequential events of a user in production?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am an amateur developer and I am wondering how to record all events of a user in my production app for debugging purposes of non-crash bugs. We would need to know sequentially how the user came to that point.

I have looked into Firebase Analytics but it doesn't seem to sequentially record sequential user-specific events and just collects all the data from the users and shows the most used functionality.

I have also looked into logging events in a .txt file locally in the User's phone but this doesn't seem optimal in my opinion.

Also Firebase Analytics DebugView only lasts 30 minutes and we would need events for a longer time frame.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question that might be solved with a lot of different ideas. My idea is to have a local SQLite database and log your user events in your local database table in a sequential manner. In order to upload the events, you might consider having a scheduler that can upload the user events recorded in a periodic manner using a web service of your own.

In that case, you need to manage your own analytics platform on your server-side.

I am not sure about Firebase Analytics, however, I think Firebase should have the capability to provide custom data presentation for the analytics recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* actually use Google Analytics for Firebase for that purpose, just not in the Firebase console.

The simplest way to get the full stream of analytics events for a user, is to enable the built-in integration from Firebase to BigQuery, and then do the analysis in BigQuery.

If you want to be able to identify the user, you will have to [set the user id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid) for the analytics events. Once you've done that, this value will also be present in the BigQuery export.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the reply. Would this require premium subscription?

Comment: There is a free sandbox on BigQuery, which you can use on Firebase's free plan. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox